# Llamadas XMLHttpRequest a variables JSON específicas creadas en PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

Tengo esta llamada **XMLHttpRequest** que me carga una variable **JSON** en array desde un **PHP**, **funciona** pero cuando hay dos variables distintas creo que el script no sabe cuál coger *(JSON.parse(this.responseText))*:

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
  var xmlhttpTipagos = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttpTipagos.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var objetoTipagos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);      
    var out = "";
    var i;           
    var myVar = 1;
    for(i = 0; i < objetoTipagos.length; i++) {
        a = myVar++;
        out += '<li>' + objetoTipagos[i].nombre_tipago + '</li>';
    }       
    document.getElementById("nombre_tipago").innerHTML = out;
  }
};
xmlhttpTipagos.open("GET", ruta+"obtenresultado.worker.php", true);
xmlhttpTipagos.send();
})
```

Mis variables están en el mismo archivo **PHP** y ofrecen resultados diferentes. Si uso dos llamadas **XMLHttpRequest** distintas que tiran de archivos **PHP** distintos me funciona bien. Hay alguna manera de llamar específicamente a una variable? Algo como ***JSON.parse(arrayTipagoJSON ) y JSON.parse(arrayIdiomasJSON)***, mi intención es recoger todos los arrays del mismo **PHP** *(obtenresultado.worker.php)* sin tener que crear un archivo por cada una.

Los arreglos los encodeo así una vez obtenidos

```
  $arrayTipagoJSON = json_encode($arrayTipago);
  $arrayIdiomasJSON = json_encode($arrayIdiomas);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución pasa por unir los arrays en PHP y mandarlos a JSON_ENCODE, más o menos así:

```
$respuesta["array1"] = $array1;
$respuesta["array2"] = $array2;
$respuesta["array3"] = $array3;
echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

para recogerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var objetoTipoTienda = JSON.parse(this.responseText);     

        console.log(objetoTipoTienda["array1"].id_tienda);
        console.log(objetoTipoTienda["array1"].nombre);
        console.log(objetoTipoTienda["array1"].apellidos);
        console.log(objetoTipoTienda["array2"]);
        console.log(objetoTipoTienda["array3"]);

  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "php.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
})
```

EDICIÓN:

```
var datosIdiomas = objetoTipoTienda["arrayIdiomas"];     
var i;
var outIdiomas='';       
for(i = 0; i < datosIdiomas.length; i++) {
outIdiomas += '<li>' + datosIdiomas[i].idioma_nombre + '</li>';
}             
console.log(outIdiomas);
```